# String substitution in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: asp.net, nopcommerce, azure-devops

I am setting up a build in Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online) for my NopCommerce application. The database connection string is defined in a file called Settings.txt and I would like the value to be updated by my build using a build variable.

I have tried using the $(varName) placeholder as suggested [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/variables) , but it didn't do anything. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed information? How do you update the value?

Comment: I'm updating the value as per the section 'Secret Variables' in the page linked to in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the variable placeholder directly in the file and there's currently no task available OOTB which does replace values inside of files. You'll need to pass it to a Script (PowerShell, Batch, etc) which replaces the value in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tokenizer task to achieve this. I don't think that it is available in VSTS by default but you can upload it. You can find the instructions to upload and use in Readme.MD
More details at these two links
http://blogs.ripple-rock.com/rorystreet/2015/11/25/UsingVSTSReleaseWithTokenisationToDeployWebsites.aspx

https://github.com/TotalALM/VSO-Tasks/tree/master/VSO%20Tasks/Tokenization